# Can we assign exact string value to an int value in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, int

In my application I have a value like "25:30" in `NSString` and I want to assign this value to int value.

If I do like:

```
int j = [stringval intValue];
```

**hence I got the value "25" to my int value but I want the full value.**
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 25.30 then you need floats, use CGFloat j = [stringval floatValue];

Answer (score 0):

If that is supposed to be minutes & seconds, use `NSDateFormatter`'s `dateFromString:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
NSString *new = @"25:30";
NSArry *data = [new componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
int first = [[data objectAtIndex:0] intValue];    \\\ 25 
int second = [[data  objectAtIndex:1] intValue];   \\\ 30
```